# What makes stack smashing detected when use ifstream?

Tags: c++, clang++

Today I get unusual error when use `clang++` and `ifstream`:

```
*** stack smashing detected ***: <unknown> terminated
```

My code looks like that:

```
uint32_t Lod::getGraphicsOffset(std::ifstream *file, int graphicsNumber) {
    uint32_t filesAmount = 0;
    fileStream.seekg(76 + graphicsNumber*32);
    fileStream.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&filesAmount), 16);
    return filesAmount;
}
```

However it's works when I change only `fileAmount` place in code like that:

```
uint32_t Lod::getGraphicsOffset(std::ifstream *file, int graphicsNumber) {
    fileStream.seekg(76 + graphicsNumber*32);
    uint32_t filesAmount = 0;
    fileStream.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&filesAmount), 16);
    return filesAmount;
}
```

Anyone know why? What is a cause of it? Maybe it is some UB?

Comment: Eeek; seek to magic number, `reinterpret_cast`, two red flags right there. Can we perhaps see a [mcve] so that we can *maybe* tell where the error is?

Comment: Guys tell me without it where error is. See, I give the esence of problem you don't need more code, it's enought.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is undefined behavior.

```
fileStream.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&filesAmount), 16);
```

Tells `fileStream` to place 16 bytes of data into `filesAmount`.  `filesAmount` however is a `uint32_t` meaning it is only 4 bytes big (assuming an 8 bit byte).  So you start writing data past the end of `filesAmount` which you are not allowed to do.  The simple fix is to change it to

```
fileStream.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&filesAmount), sizeof(filesAmount));
```

Comment: Thanks for explanation! I will probably mark it the best answer after few mins.

Answer (score 4):

In:

```
fileStream.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&filesAmount), 16);
```

That reads 16 bytes into a 4-byte `filesAmount`, which smashes stack and causes undefined behaviour.

Fix:

```
fileStream.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&filesAmount), sizeof filesAmount);
```

You should probably check the return value of `read` to make sure that it succeeded:

```
if(!fileStream.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&filesAmount), sizeof filesAmount))
    // Handle read failure.
```